# SpringBoot AWS Lambda application deployment issue-Class not found: com.abc.test.TestServiceHandler

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

Created a Spring boot application using Java 11 and trying to deploy in AWS Lambda.
Encountering the following error in AWS Lambda. I see it is an issue with the way I am packaging the jar.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: com.abc.test.TestServiceHandler",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
```

I am building the jar  using the following maven commands:

- **mvn clean install**
- mvn package -P shade

Below is my pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abc.test.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-service</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test-service</name>
    <description>Test Service</description>
    <properties>
        <revision>local-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.parent.version>2.6.4</spring.boot.parent.version>
        <commons.lang3.version>3.12.0</commons.lang3.version>
        <commons.collections.version>4.4</commons.collections.version>          <aws.sdk.secretsmanager.version>1.12.150</aws.sdk.secretsmanager.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.7</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk.secretsmanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
                    **/test/model/**/*,
                </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>sbmp</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>shade</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes>                                              <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</exclude>
                                            <exclude>*:spring-boot-devtools</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: share the main handler class which is implementing the `RequestHandler` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following sample, save as `src\main\java\com\abc\test\TestServiceHandler.java`

```
package com.abc.test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

public class TestServiceHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
  
  @Override
  public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
      LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
      logger.log("Started up");
      return;
  }
}
```

Compile, and upload jar as you mentioned in question.

In aws lambda console code tab, under Runtime settings, Handler, edit it to `com.abc.test.TestServiceHandler` to call lambda.

Point from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299255/what-interface-should-a-serverless-scheduled-java-function-implement) says use `RequestStreamHandler` instead of `RequestHandler` which [sample from doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html) used. It looks like importent.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my issue is related to my local machine (mac) that I am building my JAR from.From what I have debugged,the architecture used to build the jar is causing issues when deployed on Lambda.
Building the jar from windows machine did not cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your pom, you are missing thin layout plugin

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot.experimental/spring-boot-thin-layout -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class name should be Handler.
You can write this way....

public class Handler implements RequestStreamHandler {

@Override
public void handleRequest(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

}
}